# Unexpected geom_bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have this vector:

```
cumsum(var_prop)

 [1] 0.512527740 0.701350235 0.805488407 0.873897205 0.932390946 0.960146413
 [7] 0.974347379 0.986334249 0.995322467 1.000000000
```

And I wanted to use ggplot to plot something similar to what the built in barplot function would do.

Thats the code and the plot:

```
data_frame(val = cumsum(var_prop)) %>% ggplot(., aes(val)) + geom_bar()
```

[image: enter image description]

Sadly, its not what i was expecting, and i dont really understand wheres the problem.
I was expecting something similar to what barplot() actually returns:

```
barplot(cumsum(var_prop))
```

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are using`val` as x axis coord, try `data_frame(id = seq_along(var_prop), val = cumsum(var_prop)) %>% ggplot(aes(id, val)) + geom_col()` instead.

Comment: Yeah, thats working, thanks for your help!